# Request returns 200 in python, but an exact copy in Node.js returns 401 - What's wrong?

Tags: python, node.js, http, authentication, cookies

I am trying to send a GET request to an API using Node.JS. I don't have control over the server side. The API requires two things to be authenticated. I am getting those two values by logging in manually and then copying them over from chrome to my script.

- A cookie
- The user-agent that was used to perform the login

While this whole thing used to work a couple weeks or months ago, I now kept getting a status 401 (unauthorized). I asked a friend for help, who isn't a pro in node, but pretty good with python. He tried to build the same request with python and to our both surprise, it works perfectly fine.

So here I am, having two scripts that are supposed to do an absolutely identical action, but both have a different outcome. The request headers are both identical - since the python request works fine, it's also confirmed, that these are valid and enough to authenticate the request. They are both running on the same machine under Windows 10.

Script in **Node.JS** (returns a 401 - unauthorized):

```
const request = require("request");

const url = "https://api.rollbit.com/steam/market?query&order=1&showTradelocked=false&showCustomPriced=true&min=0&max=4294967295"

const headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'Cookie': '__Secure-RollbitSession=JWDEFp________HaLLfT'
}

request.get(url, {headers: headers, json: true}, function(err, resp, body){
    console.log(" > Response status in JS: " + resp.statusCode)
})
```

Same script in **Python** (returns a 200 - success):

```
import requests

url = "https://api.rollbit.com/steam/market?query&order=1&showTradelocked=false&showCustomPriced=true&min=0&max=4294967295"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'Cookie': '__Secure-RollbitSession=JWDEFp________HaLLfT'
}

r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
print(" > Response status: in PY:", r.status_code)
```

**Things I've tried:**

I intercepted both requests in the scripts above with [http toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech) to see if python is adding something to the headers.

***Node.JS request - returned 401***

[image: Request headers in Node.js]

***Python request - returned 200***

[image: Request headers in Python]

As seen in the intercepted results, python is adding some accept-encoding and accept headers. I tried to copy the FULL exact same headers python is sending into my node.js script, but I still get the same result (401) even though the (once again) intercepted requests now look identical.

I'm on the newest python and tried node 10.x, 12.18.0 and also the latest release.

At this point I don't know what to try any more. I don't really need it, but its completely bugging me that it isn't working for mysterious reasons and I would really like to find out what is happening.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you still seeing this? I just tested it quickly for myself, and both requests shown here now seem to 401. Either way, if the requests are identical they should behave the same, so there must be some other difference that's missing somewhere...

Comment: Hey, I actually forgot to reply here. It's still a mistery. Suddenly and up to this day, both requests work fine. Both return a 200. I have no idea about a solution. Thanks a bunch for trying :) if you have an idea, let me know! They definitely return a 401 if you don't havr a valid cookie.